# Folders within working sets?

Tags: eclipse

When using the Lotus Notes designer client, is there any way to create "folders" of database designs within the working sets? That is, either group the databases within one working set or have "sub-working-sets" that cascade in the selection list? Maybe something like this when you look at the working set selection list:

```
MyWorkingSet
  --SubMyWorkingSet
  --OtherSubMyWorkingSet
MyOtherWorkingSet
```

Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of.

You can request an enhancement request by opening a PMR or posting on ideajam.

http://ideajam.net/